# Setup cross-compile env. in eclipse for Kernel API

Tags: kernel, eclipse, gcc, arm

I'm cross compiling for a beaglebone black (that is running debian) on ubuntu and I want to make Kernel API calls from module.h, kmod.h, or firmware.h and those don't appear to be in the  arm-linux-gnueabihf package. I've tried getting the header files for the beaglebone and including them in cross gcc compiler includes section but that breaks everything (hundreds of errors). What am I missing? Googling doesn't do much good, all I get are results for cross compiling a kernel module.